# Add invisible route to Durandal project

Tags: durandal

Using the ASP.Net Durandal template in Visual Studio.  I added the following to the main.js:

```
router.mapNav('clients');
router.mapNav('client/:id');
```

These links then both work but I don't want client to be available in the navigation, if I remove that line then the link no longer works.  Is there an easy way to set it to be invisible or have I entered my routes in the wrong place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Durandal 2.0, you can specify more options for the router navigation, and it looks something like this:

```
//Durandal 2.0
router.map([
    { route: 'clients', title:'clients', moduleId: 'viewmodels/clients', nav: true},
    { route: 'client/:id', title:'client', moduleId: 'viewmodels/client', nav: false }
]).buildNavigationModel();
```

If you're using Durandal 1.x, I strongly recommend upgrading to 2.0.  There are multiple bug fixes as well as some important architectural changes that will make your life easier in the long run.

if that's not an option, there's a way in Durandal 1.x to prevent the route from appearing in the navigation as well:

```
//Durandal 1.x
router.mapRoute({ url: 'clients', name: 'clients', moduleId: 'viewmodels/clients', visible: true });
router.mapRoute({ url: 'client/:id', name: 'client', moduleId: 'viewmodels/client', visible: false });
```

With Durandal 1.x, you'll need to inspect the `visible` property of each route before adding it to a menu collection.  With 2.0, the `buildNavigationModel` function will do this automatically.

Comment: Updating Durandal appears to have knocked out the routing for some reason, now getting "Failed to load routed module" for Clients?

Comment: Think it may be related to the line:
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router');
As I use it later for router.navigateTo("#/client/" + data.ClientID);

Comment: Resolved, had to put: define(['plugins/router'],function(router) instead.

Comment: by the way, using `router.navigateTo` may require you to pass `true` as a second parameter in order to activate the new view and url correctly - not sure if that was fixed before the release or not.

Comment: Saying has no method called navigateTo?? Tried with second parameter of true and no difference...

Comment: sorry - it's router.navigate

Comment: Thanks that's done it, must have changed it as that code was working earlier!